# BLANK IMPACT MATRIX in CLIMADA

Tags: code-climate-cli

I'm trying to get an Impact Matrix in Climada from an impact object using the below codes:

Calculating impact matrix for present

```
from climada.engine import Impact

imp1 = Impact()

imp1.calc(exp, imp_set_xlsx, ts_fl, save_mat=True)
```

When I tried to print the impact matrix  << print( imp1.mat)) >>, I received the following error:

```
ValueError: Attribute imp_mat is empty. Recalculate Impactinstance with parameter save_mat=True.
```

However, I made sure `save_mat` is set True.

Answer (score 0):

In CLIMADA the impact matrix is accessed as `imp1.imp_mat` (c.f. the documentation https://climada-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/climada_engine_Impact.html )

Please note also that with the latest release 3.3 the impact computation has been modified. Now, there are two classes, `ImpactCalc` and `Impact`.

Your code would then read

```
from climada.engine import Impact, ImpactCalc

impcalc = ImpactCalc(exp, imp_set_xlsx, ts_fl)
imp1 = impcacl.impact(save_mat=True)
print(imp1.imp_mat))
```